# xfs filesystem - changing ftype=0 to ftype=1

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, docker, xfs

I have Centos 7.7 with xfs filesystems where each was created with ftype=0, for example:

```
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
```

Is is possible to change/convert it to ftype=1 without recreating/reinstalling whole system?

Docker documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/

says:

*"The overlay and overlay2 drivers are supported on xfs backing filesystems, but only with d_type=true enabled.
Use xfs_info to verify that the ftype option is set to 1. To format an xfs filesystem correctly, use the flag -n ftype=1"*

Is it possible to fix it on my current system without it's complete re-installation?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1321926/135830

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to fix it on my current system without it's complete re-installation?

Yes, it is. You can achieve this in several ways. But how easy would this be will depend on your storage architecture.
But the approximate procedure is the following,

### Approach 1:

1. Create 2 new partitions (e.g, `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/mapper/lvm-dockerd`, `/dev/mapper/lvm-containerd`)
2. Format them with `ftype=1`
3. Create 2 new directory: `/var/lib/docker` and `/var/lib/containerd`
4. Mount the newly created partitions on the above directory and reinstall docker.

### Approach 2:

1. Create a single partition (e.g, `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/mapper/lvm-storage`)
2. Format the partition with `ftype=1`
3. Create a new directory as `/storage` and mount the partition there.
4. Create 2 new directory (docker, containerd) inside the `/storage`.
5. Change the default data directory for both containerd and dockerd and point to the newly-created directory. [Doc for containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/docs/ops.md#:%7E:text=The%20default%20path%20for%20the,flags%20when%20booting%20the%20daemon.), [Doc for dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#runtime-directory-and-storage-driver)

---

**About the storage architecture,**

1. If you are using a hypervisor like vmware then you could just add some virtual disk easily.
2. If you are using LVM to manage your partition, you can just shrink the [lvm volume](https://askubuntu.com/a/196134/712320) and create new volume.
3. If you have any NFS server you can just create and mount NFS directory to the `/var/lib/docker` or appropriate directory.
4. If you have neither then you have to add a new disk and create necessary partitions (I hope with lvm) then proceed with the above instruction.